# Preserve markdown file formatting using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, markdown, json-server

I am using [json-server custom output](https://github.com/typicode/json-server#custom-output-example) to read md file and return it as it is to the client, so I wrote this code:

```
server.get('/static/*', (req, res) => {

  const filePath = path.join(__dirname, `myfile.md`);
  fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      res.send(err);
      return;
    }
    res.send(data);
  });
});
```

The code is working but response does not preserve any file formatting. So I wonder how would you fix that?

Original file:

[image]

Response:

[image]

As you can see the response all goes into one line which is not expected result.

Comment: that code will send the content of `myfile.md` exactly as is - what makes you believe it does not? (unless the files character encoding is not utf8 I guess) Can you give a short example of say the first few lines of `myfile.md` on the server and what the client receives

Comment: What do you mean by “preserving formatting”? Markdown files are plain text; there’s no formatting. Do you actually mean you want it rendered as HTML?

Comment: Actually, markdown DOES have formatting ... new lines and preserving leading/trailing spaces are important "formatting" for markdown to work @DaveNewton 

Comment: just updated the question with more details

Comment: so, the response has lost the newlines!! Must be something the client code is doing

Comment: @JaromandaX it is just a plain response within a browser window. Theoretically may be https://github.com/typicode/json-server does something, but it is less likely because I am using a plain `res.send()`

Comment: `within a browser window` - you mean you dump the received markdown into a HTML element? of course the line breaks disappear, `\n` is just the same as a space in HTML ... perhaps you want to use a `<pre>` element to display the raw markdown you want to show - or add `white-space: pre` style to the element you use to display the raw markdown

Comment: @JaromandaX no I didn't, to test the result at first place I am calling the server api directly in the browser window, it is just a simple get method

Comment: "calling the API directly" ... then what? how are you viewing the result?

Comment: @JaromandaX I guess I just "fixed" the problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/73074198/2926340, thanks for the hint, currently wondering if there anyway to force browser to Raw response without fiddling with network tabs

Comment: server sending header `content-type: text/plain` would probably fix that

Comment: @JaromandaX https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73074309/change-json-server-response-type-for-custom-route-notacceptableerror-not-accep

Answer (score 0):

Oh it was my bad, I inspected the result in network tab [image]

There I incidentally discovered a `Raw switch` option, so by switching that I discovered the actual response

[image]

Comment: I believe this would also be fixed if the server sent `text/plain` as the `content-type` for the response - I would recommend that