# Change json-server response type for custom route. NotAcceptableError: Not Acceptable

Tags: javascript, node.js, content-type, json-server

I am using [json-server custom output](https://github.com/typicode/json-server#custom-output-example) to read md file. I want to return the contend on specific rout as `text/plain`, so I wrote this code:

```
server.get('/static/*', (req, res) => {

  const filePath = path.join(__dirname, `myfile.md`);
  fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      res.send(err);
      return;
    }
    res.format({
     'content-type: text/plain': () => res.send(data),
    });
  });
});
```

When I am accessing that route I am getting an error `NotAcceptableError: Not Acceptable` Any ideas how to fix?

Comment: why are you using `res.format` - just `res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain'); res.send(data);` - also read how res.format is actually used in the [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#res.format) - I see no example close to what you did

Comment: @JaromandaX right, fixed! feel free to post that as an answer otherwise this question does not make any more sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`res.format` is not what you want to use. You use `res.set` to set a response header - like so:

```
server.get('/static/*', (req, res) => {
    const filePath = path.join(__dirname, `myfile.md`);
    fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
            return;
        }
        res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
        res.send(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: oh, btw, I was changed `'content-type: text/plain': () => res.send(data),` to `'text/plain': () => res.send(data),` and it works too

Comment: @sreginogemoh - I'll have to check out this `res.format` - seems interesting